# How can I output integers in a txt to a form that can be used in creating a new class?

Tags: python

I currently have a polynomial class that can be created like this:

```
P = Polynomial((6,14), (9,11), (-12, 3), (42,0)
```

and if you did str(P) you would get:

```
6x^14 + 9x^11 - 12x^3 + 42
```

Now I have a txt file that looks similar to this:

```
6 14
9 11
-12 3
42 0
```

and I need to have it read by a function that will output a new Polynomial class like the above.

My current code looks like this:

```
def read_polynomial(polyfilename):
    infileobj = open(polyfilename, 'r')
    final = []
    for line in infileobj.readlines():
        final.append(line.split())
    infileobj.close()
    return final
```

But it outputs a list that looks like this:

```
[['6', '14'], ['9', '11'], ['-12', '3'], ['42', '0']]
```

And anything I try to change it into a useable format that will let me implement it into the class seems to fail.  So how can I fix this code to do my bidding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this reading code work for you?

```
def read_polynomial(polyfilename):
    infileobj = open(polyfilename, 'r')
    final = []
    for line in infileobj.readlines():
        nums = line.split()
        final.append( (float(nums[0]), int(nums[1])) )
    infileobj.close()
    return final
```

A slightly more concise version using `with open()`:

```
def read_polynomial(path):
  final = []
  with open(path, 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
      nums = line.split()
      final.append( (float(nums[0]), int(nums[1])) )
  return final
```

Comment: It didn't exactly work but it did enough.  I was able to convert the final = [] to a tuple and then make a new Polynomial class with     nP = Polynomial(*sfinal)

But thanks a bunch! +1

Answer (score 1):

Use `*iterable` like this (I have modified final to a list of tuples rather than a list of lists):

```
def read_polynomial(polyfilename):
    infileobj = open(polyfilename, 'r')
    final = []
    for line in infileobj.readlines():
        final.append(tuple(line.split())) # Append tuple rather than another list
    infileobj.close()
    return final

args = read_polynomial(polyfilename)
P = Polynomial(*args)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to type cast the values from strings to integer type. Try this:

```
def read_polynomial(polyfilename):
    infileobj = open(polyfilename, 'r')
    final = []
    for line in infileobj.readlines():
        line = [int(x) for x in line.split()]
        final.append(line)
    infileobj.close()
    return final
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can pass the `final` list into `Polynomial`.  Change the last line of `read_polynomial` to:

```
return Polynomial(*final)
```